# KNN in R -- All arguments must have the same length, test.X is empty

Tags: r, classification, knn

I'm trying to perform KNN in R on a dataframe, following 3-way classification for vehicle types (car, boat, plane), using columns such as mpg, cost as features.

To start, when I run:

```
knn.pred=knn(train.X,test.X,train.VehicleType,k=3)
```

then

```
knn.pred
```

returns

```
factor(0) Levels: car boat plane
```

And

```
table(knn.pred,VehicleType.All)
```

returns

```
Error in table(knn.pred, VehicleType.All) : 
  all arguments must have the same length
```

I think my problem is that I can successfully load train.X with cbind() but when I try the same for test.X it remains an empty matrix. My code looks like this:

```
train=(DATA$Values<=200) # to train for all 200 entries including cars, boats and planes
```

```
train.X = cbind(DATA$mpg,DATA$cost)[train,]
summary(train.X)
```

Here, summary(train.X) returns correctly, but when I try the same for test.X:

```
test.X = cbind(DATA$mpg,DATA$cost)[!train,]
```

When I try and print test.X it returns an empty matrix like so:

```
[,1] [,2]
```

Apologies for such a long question and I'm probably not including all relevant info. If anyone has any idea what's going wrong here or why my test.X isn't loading through any data I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any info on your data, it is hard to guess where the problem is. You should post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
or at least `dput` your data or part of it. However here I show 2 methods for training a `knn` model, using 2 different package (`class`, and `caret`) with the `mtcars` built-in dataset.

**with `class`**

```
library(class)

data("mtcars")
str(mtcars)
mtcars$gear <- as.factor(mtcars$gear)
ind <- sample(1:nrow(mtcars),20)
train.X <- mtcars[ind,]
test.X <- mtcars[-ind,]
train.VehicleType <- train.X[,"gear"]
VehicleType.All <- test.X[,"gear"]
knn.pred=knn(train.X,test.X,train.VehicleType,k=3)

table(knn.pred,VehicleType.All)
```

**with `caret`**

```
library(caret)

ind <- createDataPartition(mtcars$gear,p=0.60,list=F)
train.X <- mtcars[ind,]
test.X <- mtcars[-ind,]
control <-trainControl(method = "cv",number = 10)
grid <- expand.grid(k=2:10)
knn.pred <- train(gear~.,data=train.X,method="knn",tuneGrid=grid)
pred <- predict(knn.pred,test.X[,-10])
cm <- confusionMatrix(pred,test.X$gear)
```

the `caret` package allows performing cross-validation for parameters tuning during model fitting, in a straightforward way. By default `train` perform a 25 rep bootstrap cross-validation to find the best value of `k` among the values I've supplied in the `grid` object.

From your example, it seems that your test object is empty so the result of `knn` is a 0-length vector. Probably your problem is in the data reading. However, a better way to subset your `DATA` can be this:

```
#insetad of
train.X = cbind(DATA$mpg,DATA$cost)[train,]

#you should do:
train.X <- DATA[train,c("mpg","cost")]
test.X <- DATA[-train,c("mpg","cost")]
```

However, I do not understand what variable is `DATA$Values`, Firstly I was thinking it was the outcome, but, this line confused me a lot:

`train=(DATA$Values<=200)`

You can work on these examples to catch your error on your own. If you can't post an example that reproduces your situation.